# Inconsistent behaviour of IBeacon with IOS7

Tags: ios7, bluetooth, core-location, ibeacon

I started to play around with my very new IBeacon devices.

I wrote some test app, to understand region monitoring, ranging behaviour in real life.

According to my experiences:

- monitoring didEnterRegion/didExitRegion behaves inconsistently. Several times, when ranging can see devices, didEnterRegion is not called immediately, only several minutes (sometimes 5 minutes) later. As opposite, when ranging can not see any devices, didExitRegion does not come immediately, only some minutes later.
- proximity is highly inaccurate
- several times when monitoring regions, it calls both didExitRegion/didEnterRegion in a second, even if devices and my IPhone is on the same place

As a result, I can not make the following - trivial - workflow:

- geofence beacon monitoring
- when enter a region by monitoring, start ranging
- when exit a region by monitoring, stop ranging

So, some data filtering, post processing needed, before make some actions according to IBeacon monitoring. As it is a quite new technology, with a very low number of beacons out there, it is nearly impossible to find real life samples (except trivial sample codes coming from docs, not from real life), experiences, and find answers to these kind of questions.

Does anybody have experiences with it? If so, does he see this problems like me? Are there any common workflows, patterns to solve it?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Following the common workflow given in WWDC videos 2013, I am able to use beacons. Ya, i m getting problems with proximity(not that much), otherwise didEnterRegion and didExitRegion is going good with me. This problem that, you cant define exact boundary for region.....

Comment: I am also able to use, it is trivial. My question is not about that. Thanks MDTakhar!